# asp .net mvc 5 cannot find context class after generating models using Database first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

i am learning how to work with asp .net because i need to but as i am following the database first approach http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/generating-views
& after i generated the models with ado .net the way it's shown i cannot find a context class, there is not a single one i added one  manually, just to see if it might work, but still nothing & i was wondering why
i am using vs 13 free community & EF 6
thank you in advance

**EDIT :**
I fixed it after re-making the steps & now it appears
thank you for your help it brought me the idea to do so  
**PS :** I think the issue was due to me having an older  version of SSDT & i had to update it after bringing in the DB due to failure when building project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your link, on page 'Creating the Web Application and Data Models'.

He says this:
'The ContosoModel.Context.cs file contains a class that derives from the DbContext class, and provides a property for each model class that corresponds to a database table. The Course.cs, Enrollment.cs, and Student.cs files contain the model classes that represent the databases tables. You will use both the context class and the model classes when working with scaffolding.'

Can't you find it here?